# NUCLEO-F429ZI LED's wont blink

Tags: stm32, gpio, nucleo

Good day

The problem:

- I am trying to blink the three LED's on the board, but the LED's are not blinking

What I have done:

- Using CubeMX I have configured the board using the default pinout.
  `PB0 = LD1, PB7 = LD2, PB14 = LD3`
- I have added these lines to `main.c` to blink the LED. Please note I have commented out the Ethernet Init due to the expected hard fault as I have not configured ethernet and memory.

```
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  //MX_ETH_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, 0);
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, 7);
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, 14);

      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
```

Observations:

- With the above lines of code only LD3 will blink. IF I try blink only LD3 and comment out the other two blink commands, then LD3 no longer blinks
- If I set the startup conditions of the three LEDs to high (in either the gpio.c or in CubeMX) then all three LEDs turn on, but they will not blink thereafter.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: First thing I would do, is set all 3 high or low, then go into the toggle loop. I would also read the pins after toggle and output the result to the console.

Comment: Im using STlink debugging. So I have added breakpoints to the loop and the loop is executing properly. Ive tried setting them high prior to the while loop too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With much embarrassment, this is the problem. The API HAL_GPIO_TogglePin() requires very specific arguments.

The following examples do not work:

```
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(A,12);
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,12);
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(A,GPIO_Pin_12);
```

Please make sure you use the proper handles and arguments:

```
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_Pin_12);
```